# Domain and range of atypical piecewise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am tasked with finding the domain and range of 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{if $x$ is an integer},\\[0.25em]
0 & \text{if $x$ is not an integer},
\end{cases}
$$
as well as 
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{if $x$ is rational},\\[0.25em]
0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational}.
\end{cases}
$$
It seems $f$ and $g$ both have the same domain, $\mathbb{R}$, but the range question is more interesting. For $f$, it would appear that the range is $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ while the range of $g$ is more complicated. Would it be that the range is the set of all fractions of the form $\alpha/\beta$, where $\alpha,\beta$ are perfect squares (including 0)? Is there a better way of showing this or writing it?

Comment: You are correct about the domains, but be careful with the ranges. As stated, you do not have the correct range for f(x).

Comment: Oops--I meant all positive *perfect squares*, not just positive integers. And including 0 of course.

Comment: Then I think you have everything correct. I don't think you need to show your work about the range of g(x), it seems self evident to me. As for writing it, I think you are probably fine as is. Maybe say something about $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being coprime?

Comment: You are OK with $g$, but you need to make some similar restrictions for $f$:, e.g.,  $3 \not\in \mbox{ran}(f)$.